# Trying to install modules with Perl

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I use Strawberry on windows and I'm trying to install couple of modules (PDL::Lite,PDL::Basic,PDL::MatrixOps,PDL::LinearAlgebra and Math::Random).

I was able to install through CPAN the modules PDL::Basic, Math::Random. I had an error message (error code 129, while making '..\blib\arch\auto\PDL\LinearAlgebra\Trans\Trans.dll'; and error code 255, while making 'subdirs') when trying to install PDL::LinearAlgebra.

```
cpan> install PDL::LinearAlgebra
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Database was generated on Wed, 19 Feb 2014 16:49:52 GMT

Updating database file ...
Done!
Running install for module 'PDL::LinearAlgebra'
Running make for C/CH/CHM/PDL-LinearAlgebra-0.08.tar.gz
Checksum for C:\strawberry\cpan\sources\authors\id\C\CH\CHM\PDL-LinearAlgebra-0.
08.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\strawberry\cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE


  CPAN.pm: Building C/CH/CHM/PDL-LinearAlgebra-0.08.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
WARNING: LDLOADLIBS is not a known parameter.
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for PDL::LinearAlgebra::Trans
WARNING: LDLOADLIBS is not a known parameter.
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for PDL::LinearAlgebra::Real
WARNING: LDLOADLIBS is not a known parameter.
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for PDL::LinearAlgebra::Complex
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for PDL::LinearAlgebra::Special
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for PDL::LinearAlgebra
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp LinearAlgebra.pm blib\lib\PDL\LinearAlgebra.pm
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -IC:/strawberry/perl/site/lib "-MPDL::PP qw/PDL:
:LinearAlgebra::Trans PDL::LinearAlgebra::Trans Trans/" trans.pd
cp Trans.pm ..\blib\lib\PDL\LinearAlgebra/Trans.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for PDL::LinearAlgebra::Trans ()
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Command -e chmod -- 644 Trans.bs
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe C:\strawberry\perl\lib\ExtUtils\xsubpp  -typemap
 C:\strawberry\perl\lib\ExtUtils\typemap -typemap C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/PD
L/Core/typemap.pdl  Trans.xs > Trans.xsc && C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -MEx
tUtils::Command -e mv -- Trans.xsc Trans.c
gcc -c  -IC:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/PDL/Core  -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERV
ATIVE -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_
PERLIO -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -s -O2         -DVERSION=\"0.08\"
-DXS_VERSION=\"0.08\"  "-IC:\strawberry\perl\lib\CORE"   Trans.c
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -MExtUtils::Mksymlists \
     -e "Mksymlists('NAME'=>\"PDL::LinearAlgebra::Trans\", 'DLBASE' => 'Trans',
'DL_FUNCS' => {  }, 'FUNCLIST' => [], 'IMPORTS' => {  }, 'DL_VARS' => []);"
dlltool --def Trans.def --output-exp dll.exp
g++ -o ..\blib\arch\auto\PDL\LinearAlgebra\Trans\Trans.dll -Wl,--base-file -Wl,d
ll.base -mdll -s -L"C:\strawberry\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\strawberry\c\lib" Trans.o
   C:\strawberry\perl\lib\CORE\libperl518.a oldnames.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib
 gdi32.lib winspool.lib  comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut3
2.lib  netapi32.lib uuid.lib wsock32.lib mpr.lib winmm.lib  version.lib odbc32.l
ib odbccp32.lib msvcrt.lib  ../lapack/libacml.lib "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Vi
sual Studio .NET 2003\Vc7\lib\msvcrt.lib" dll.exp
g++: error: oldnames.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: kernel32.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: user32.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: gdi32.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: winspool.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: comdlg32.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: advapi32.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: shell32.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: ole32.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: oleaut32.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: netapi32.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: uuid.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: wsock32.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: mpr.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: winmm.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: version.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: odbc32.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: odbccp32.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: msvcrt.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: ../lapack/libacml.lib: No such file or directory
g++: error: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Vc7\lib\msvcrt.li
b: No such file or directory
dmake:  Error code 129, while making '..\blib\arch\auto\PDL\LinearAlgebra\Trans\
Trans.dll'
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'subdirs'
  CHM/PDL-LinearAlgebra-0.08.tar.gz
  C:\strawberry\c\bin\dmake.exe -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'PDL::LinearAlgebra'.
Failed during this command:
 CHM/PDL-LinearAlgebra-0.08.tar.gz            : make NO
```

I couldn't find PDL::Lite and PDL::MatrixOps so I downloaded them, but when i try to use gzip -d PDL-2.007.tar.gz in the directory C:\Users\home\Downloads, it says 'gzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I do have winzip on my computer. I can manually unzip the file, but then I don't have 'tar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I hope someone can help me with that

Thanks

Comment: gzip is not standard on windows, install [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). Also, your post isn't helpful. Post properly formatted cpan installation attempts.

Comment: I have posted the installation attempt and I do actually have 7zip installed on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't read the [README](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CHM/PDL-LinearAlgebra-0.08/README):

```
DEPENDENCIES

This module requires PDL and working BLAS and LAPACK libraries.
```